# Combine 3 x sql queries on oracle db into 1

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle-apex

Firstly apologies if this seems very trivial but I have been trying this on my own for a while with not much success hence asking for assistance. Below are 3 x sql queries (Point 1,2,3) which I want to be combined as a single query giving output shown in point 4.(RDATE,CODATE,COMDATE are columns in Table "ORTABLE" and are type 'DATE' in format mm/dd/yyyy.STATUS is also one of the columns in table and has different status values on which filters are placed to get subsequent counts and ordered by Months.

```
select to_char(RDATE, 'MON RRRR') AS MONTH,
       COUNT(STATUS) as "NEW" 
from ORTABLE 
GROUP BY to_char(RDATE, 'MON RRRR'), to_char(RDATE, 'RRRR MM') 
order by to_char(RDATE, 'RRRR MM');

Output
MONTH              NEW
MAR 2020          19
APR 2020            76
MAY 2020           33
JUN 2020            18
JUL 2020             27
AUG 2020           82
SEP 2020             29
OCT 2020            25
NOV 2020           53
DEC 2020            1
JAN 2021            40
FEB 2021            4

select to_char(CODATE, 'MON RRRR') AS MONTH,
       COUNT(STATUS) as "STATUSANB" 
from ORTABLE where STATUS IN ('STATUSA','STATUSB') 
GROUP BY to_char(CODATE, 'MON RRRR'), to_char(CODATE, 'RRRR MM') 
order by to_char(CODATE, 'RRRR MM') ;

Output
MONTH      STATUSANB
SEP 2020    9
OCT 2020    12
NOV 2020    2
DEC 2020    1
JAN 2021    39
FEB 2021    1

select to_char(COMDATE , 'MON RRRR') AS MONTH,
       COUNT(STATUS) as "Completed" 
from ORTABLE 
where STATUS IN ('STATUSC','STATUSD','STATUSE') 
GROUP BY to_char(COMDATE , 'MON RRRR'),to_char(COMDATE , 'RRRR MM') 
order by to_char(COMDATE , 'RRRR MM') ;

Output
MONTH   Completed
APR 2020    1
MAY 2020    71
JUN 2020    48
JUL 2020    34
AUG 2020    37
SEP 2020    19
OCT 2020    62
NOV 2020    3
DEC 2020    42
JAN 2021    23
FEB 2021    1
```

I am looking to get sql query such that I can get data in below format

```
Month      NEW   STATUSANB      Completed
MAR 2020    19      
APR  2020   76                    1
MAY 2020    33                    71
JUN 2020    18                    48
JUL 2020    27                    34
AUG 2020    82                    37
SEP 2020    29         9           19
OCT 2020    25        12           62
NOV 2020    53         2           3
DEC 2020    1          1           42
JAN 2021    40        39           23
FEB 2021    4          1           1
```

If someone could spare some time and advice, it would be appreciated.Thanks.
Attaching image to make better sense of output of 3x queries and combined output expected
[3xsql queries output and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kibMK.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different date columns.  One way to handle this is to use `union all` and then aggregate.  As a matter of preference, I prefer `trunc()` rather than converting the dates to a string, so I'll use that:

```
select trunc(dte, 'MON'),
       sum(is_new), sum(is_anb), sum(is_completed)
from ((select rdate as dte, 1 as is_new, null as is_anb, null as is_completed
       from ORTABLE
      ) union all
      (select codate as dte, null as is_new, 1, null
       from ORTABLE
       where STATUS IN ('STATUSA', 'STATUSB')
      ) union all
      (select comdate, null, null as is_new, 1 as is_completed
       from ORTABLE
       where STATUS IN ('STATUSC', 'STATUSD', 'STATUSE') 
      ) 
     ) d
group by trunc(dte, 'MON')
order by trunc(dte, 'MON');
```

Comment: Thank you.This almost gives the output desired .But one of the reason to use to_char was to have the month column in MON YYYY format rather than mm/01/yyyy . I am trying to conver this back using to_char but not sure if it will sort as expected
MONTH is_new is_anb is_completed
03/01/2020 19 -  -
04/01/2020 76 -  1
05/01/2020 33 -  40
06/01/2020 18 -  47
07/01/2020 27 -  31
08/01/2020 82 -  36
09/01/2020 29 9 19
10/01/2020 25 12 62
11/01/2020 53 2 3
12/01/2020 1 1 42
01/01/2021 45 39 23
02/01/2021 4 1 1

Comment: @Ashwsur . . . You can just replace the `trunc()` with `to_char()`.  As I say, this is my preferences to avoid converting dates to strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation and combine all 3 queries into one:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(RDATE, 'MON RRRR') AS MONTH,
    COUNT(STATUS) AS "NEW",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('STATUSA', 'STATUSB') THEN 1 END) AS STATUSANB,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('STATUSC', 'STATUSD', 'STATUSE') THEN 1 END) AS Completed
FROM ORTABLE
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(RDATE, 'MON RRRR')
ORDER BY
    TO_CHAR(RDATE, 'MON RRRR');
```

Comment: Do you seen any reason to GROUP BY both TO_CHAR(RDATE, 'MON RRRR' **and** TO_CHAR(RDATE, 'RRRR MM')?

Comment: @jarlh No, I don't.  I was just scrutinizing that as a matter of fact.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks this gets me closer.Only catch is since RDATE is used as the only date to sort/group,  "STATUSANB" case count  is skewed since it depends on CODATE and "Completed" count is dependent on COMDATE.

Comment: I didn't even see this, and I thought there was only one date column involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses and the edits for my rookie table format posting..
Below query sort of works for me.I tried with MON/YYYY format but due to string in month format it skews the sort order.Unless there is better way to do the MON sort format I am going to work with MM/YY format..

```
select to_char(dte, 'MM/YY') ,
   sum(is_new) , sum(is_anb) , sum(is_completed)
```

from ((select rdate as dte, 1 as is_new, null as is_anb, null as is_completed
from ORTABLE
) union all
(select codate as dte, null as Enter, 1, null
from ORTABLE
where STATUS IN ('STATUSA', 'STATUSB')
) union all
(select comdate, null, null as Enter, 1 as Completed
from ORTABLE
where STATUS IN ('STATUSC', 'STATUSD', 'STATUSE')
)
) d
group by to_char(dte, 'MM/YY'),to_char(dte, 'YY/MM')
order by to_char(dte, 'YY/MM');